# Codeigniter Restful API not working

Tags: php, codeigniter, rest

I have a Codeigniter setup where I installed the Restful API thing. I created an API-folder in my `application->controller->api` and after that i created an API which looks like this:

```
<?php

require(APPPATH.'libraries/REST_Controller.php');

class Allartists extends REST_Controller{

function artists_get()
{
    if(!$this->get('artist_id'))
    {
        $this->response(NULL, 400);
    }

    $artists = $this->artist_model->get( $this->get('artist_id') );

    if($artists)
    {
        $this->response($artists, 200);
    }
    else
    {
        $this->response(array('error' => 'Couldn\'t find any artists!'), 404);
    }
}

?>
```

In my `application->models`-folder I have the file `artist_model.php` which looks like this:

```
<?php

Class artist_model extends CI_Model
{
   function get_all_artists(){
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('artists');
    return $this->db->get();
   }
}

?>
```

So, when I type `http://localhost/myprojects/ci/index.php/api/Allartists/artists/` I get `400 - Bad Request`-error... when I type `http://localhost/myprojects/ci/index.php/api/Allartists/artists/artist_id/100` I get PHP error `Undefined property: Allartists::$artist_model` - So what is going on here?

Answer (score 0):

You need to load your model.  Add a constructor to `Allartists` and load it.

```
class Allartists extends REST_Controller{

   function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('Artist_model');
    }

    // ...
}
```

P.S. Your model needs to have the 1st letter in its class name capitalized (see: http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/models.html):

```
class Artist_model extends CI_Model{
    // ...
}
```

UPDATE: You are looking for `$this->get('artist_id')`.  This will never be set as you are not sending a `$_GET['artist_id']` value (`?artist_id=100` in the URL).  You need to get the `$artist_id` another way in your controller.

```
function artists_get($artist_id=FALSE)
{
    if($artist_id === FALSE)
    {
        $this->response(NULL, 400);
    }

    $artists = $this->artist_model->get( $artist_id );

    if($artists)
    {
        $this->response($artists, 200);
    }
    else
    {
        $this->response(array('error' => 'Couldn\'t find any artists!'), 404);
    }
}
```

Then go to:

```
http://localhost/myprojects/ci/index.php/api/Allartists/artists/100
```

*Or*, keeping your current code, you could simply change the URL to:

```
http://localhost/myprojects/ci/index.php/api/Allartists/artists?artist_id=100
```

Comment: Try `$this->Artist_model->get`?  Do you get the *same* error or a different one?

Comment: `$this->get('artist_id')` will always be false.  You aren't passing a `$_GET['artist_id']` value.

Comment: This still doesn't work... Could it be the `artist_id`? Its a column in the DB-table `artists`

Comment: How does it not work?  Do you still see the same error?  Have you tried to `var_dump($artist_id)` and/or `var_dump($artists)` to see what's in them?

Comment: Before `if($artist_id === FALSE)`.  Make sure you are going to `/api/Allartists/artists/100`.

Comment: Both `$artist_id` and `$artists` are undefined... how can that be? I was following the examples from http://cmstutorials.org/tutorial/view/working_with_restful_services_in_codeigniter ... I dont get it

Comment: What does "undefined" mean?  PHP doesn't have "undefined"?  Is it `NULL` or `FALSE`?